# Power-over-Ethernet: 100 Mbps Device compatible with 1 Gbps Source?

Tags: networking, ethernet, electrical-power, power-over-ethernet

I have an IP Camera, which is supports Power-over-Ethernet. The relating Ethernet Switch on the camera supports 100Mbs.

Now when I want to support the camera with Power over Ethernet, will it be compatible with an 1Gbps switch?

Comment: what is the switch? Can it inject PoE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two Power-over-Ethernet standards;

IEEE 802.3af-2003 (PoE) which supports 12.95-15.4w (depending on the length/attenuation of the cable)
IEEE 802.3at-2009 (PoE+) which supports up to 25.5w (again depending on the cable).

So you need to understand what the cameras requirements are and then look at both switches but ensure it'll work but certainly if the 1Gbps switch supports '.3at' then I'm sure it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can run 100-megabit PoE devices on a Gigabit PoE-enabled switch.